# Securing loose lampholder to lamp base

Tags: uk, lamp

I have replaced the lampholder on an old lamp. The lampholder came with a double ended screw part which looks like it is intended to clamp around the top hole along with the nipple. However the hole at the bottom is much too small to get my hand through (and my chopstick skills are not there yet), so I'm not sure how I can secure it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would hot glue the spinny part to the lip where it needs to be, then rotate the whole assembly to tighten the screw, letting the cord freely rotate as I do so. If the cord can't free-rotate, pre-twist the "wrong way" several times so that tightening undoes your twist. If you need to remove it later, simply unscrew, then heat the hot glue with a hair dryer and it will pop back off; it only has to hold the nut/bolt in place to tighten.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Install the anchor tube before connecting the cord.

Disconnect the cord from the lampholder and use a tube-spanner, nut driver, or extended socket to turn and tighten the nut.

Use a string to pull the wire though the tube and then reconnect it to the lampholder

Screw the lamp-holder back onto the plastic tube taking care not to tangle the cord inside the lamp base.